# Performance of List representation of MonadPlus versus Tree representation

Tags: haskell, tree, monads

I am working on a code where I represent a `MonadPlus` using a `Tree` data structure and then explore it, summing over all of the leaves (whose type must be an instance of `Monoid`);  I need to use a `Tree` representation to do this (rather than using the `List` representation) because as I explore the tree I want to manually keep track of things like my position in the `Tree` for checkpointing and workload balancing purposes.

My problem is that using a `Tree` data structure is slower than using the `List` data structure by a factor of ~ 4 for small depths (~ 1-10) and ~ 2.5 for higher depths (~15), and I am having trouble understanding exactly why this is;  in particular I am wondering if there are tricks that I can employ to make my code faster.

The remainder of this question will be some code that I wrote to benchmark `Tree` versus List. I will present my code in sections.  First, the prelude:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Control.DeepSeq
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Operational

import Criterion.Main

import Data.Functor.Identity
import Data.Monoid
```

My `Tree` type is defined using functionality in the `operational` package by specifying the type of instructions and then use `operational` to obtain a `Program` monad from this.

```
data TreeTInstruction m α where
    Choice :: TreeT m α -> TreeT m α -> TreeTInstruction m α
    Null :: TreeTInstruction m α

newtype TreeT m α = TreeT { unwrapTreeT :: ProgramT (TreeTInstruction m) m α } deriving (Monad)

type Tree = TreeT Identity

instance Monad m => MonadPlus (TreeT m) where
    mzero = TreeT . singleton $ Null
    left `mplus` right = TreeT . singleton $ Choice left right
```

The following two functions respectively build a perfect binary tree with `Sum Int` at all the leaves (which can be any type that is an instance `MonadPlus`) and explore a given `Tree`.

```
makeTree :: MonadPlus m => Int -> m (Sum Int)
makeTree 0 = return (Sum 1)
makeTree d = makeTree (d-1) `mplus` makeTree (d-1)

exploreTree :: Tree (Sum Int) -> Sum Int
exploreTree v =
    case view (unwrapTreeT v) of
        Return x -> x
        Choice left right :>>= k ->
            let x = exploreTree $ left >>= TreeT . k
                y = exploreTree $ right >>= TreeT . k
                xy = mappend x y
            in xy
```

As a technicality we need to write an instance of `NFData` for `Sum Int` for the benchmarking code.

```
instance NFData (Sum Int) where
    rnf s@(Sum x) = x `seq` s `seq` ()
```

Finally, we have the benchmarking code.  First, it benchmarks using `makeTree` to construct a tree using the List monad and then using `mconcat` to sum over all the results, and second, it benchmarks using `makeTree` using the `Tree` monad and sums over all the leaves using the `exploreTree` function.

```
main = defaultMain
    [bench "list" $ nf (mconcat . makeTree) depth
    ,bench "tree" $ nf (exploreTree . makeTree) depth
    ]
  where
    depth = 1 -- this is a knob that controls the tree size
```

For benchmarks, the list and tree times were as follows on my machine:

```
       List    Tree  Tree/List
 1:   140ns   460ns  3.3x
 2:   330ns  1300ns  4.0x
 4:  1600ns  6300ns  3.9x
 8:    32us   130us  4.0x
10:   150us   600us  4.0x
12:   990us  2900us  2.9x
14:   4.6ms    12ms  2.6x
16:    24ms    55ms  2.3x
17:    50ms   110ms  2.2x
```

(17 is the largest depth because after that exploring the list causes a stack overflow.)

If anyone has advice on exactly what the cause is of this slow down and if anything can be done about it then I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail what task you'd like to solve? This would help to understand the program and offer alternative solutions.

Comment: My project involves automatically parallelizing searches through trees;  to do this I need an efficient representation for non-deterministic computations as a Monad that I can interpret as a tree, as the branches in the tree give me workloads that I can send to other workers to explore in parallel.  For more details, project page is [here](https://github.com/gcross/LogicGrowsOnTrees).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late, but perhaps it'll still help someone.

From the benchmark it's not clear if the time difference is caused by producing a tree or consuming it. I'm not very familiar with *operational* to make a guess.

It seems that what you're looking for is a [free](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/free-monad-transformers.html) `MonadPlus`. The closest to this is probably `FreeT f []` using [`FreeT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Free.html#t:FreeT), see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32185389/1333025). I tried to benchmark it with your code with

```
exploreFreeTree :: FreeT Identity [] (Sum Int) -> Sum Int
exploreFreeTree = mconcat . iterT runIdentity
```

that flattens a tree into a list and then concatenates it, and it was almost as fast as plain `[]`.

But there is another potential problem. For free monads the bind operation `>>=` needs to traverse the whole sequence of operations in the left argument, which can cause performance issues. It's similar to appending two lists. I don't know if *operational* has a similar problem or not. For free monads the solution is to use the `Codensity` monad, in particular it's enough to just wrap your computation with [`improve`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Codensity.html#v:improve). For this it might be better to use `Free []` instead of `FreeT [] Identity` (although I haven't checked the details), as `Codensity` works only on `Free`, not `FreeT`.

It might be relevant to read 
[Is there a Codensity MonadPlus that asymptotically optimizes a sequence of MonadPlus operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32252312/1333025), although it's somewhat complicated stuff.

An good alternative could be to use [logict](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/logict-0.6.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Logic.html). You could express your computations using [`MonadLogic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/logict-0.6.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Logic-Class.html#t:MonadLogic) and then [run](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/logict-0.6.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Logic.html#v:runLogicT) your computation in `LogicT` to do whatever processing you need to do. The advantage of this is that `LogicT` is internally build with continuations, which alleviates the problem with `>>=` performance of `Free`, and is built exactly to deal with branching computations. If you'd be interested, I could try to work out an example.

Comment: I've moved on from that problem, but thank you for the information!  :-)